# Python: Pandas Parallel Coordinates Ranges of Axes and Labeling

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have the following question. Is it possible in Parallel Coordinates in Pandas to give all y axes a different range of numbers and labeling? Because with the example approach of pandas it is only possible that the ranges of all axes is oriented to the highest range of columns:

[image]

But it should more look like here:

[image]

Comment: In Pandas diretly it seems not possible (tried myself), but using matplotlib directly there are ways. Look e.g. here: http://benalexkeen.com/parallel-coordinates-in-matplotlib/

Comment: Ok it seems like in plotly it is possible ( in fact the 2nd plot is from plotly) and not hard to implement:)